# Regular expression for an identifier that is not a keyword

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wish to create a regular expression (in Python if that matters) such that it checks if a variable is a valid identifier for another language.

So far I have the following:

```
[A-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*
```

However,I wish to extend the above regular expression so that it does not match keywords e.g. "new", "false", "true", "for", "while"

How can I do this?

Comment: `A-z` is wrong, since it include ```[ \ ] ^ _ ` ```. Use `A-Za-z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) here:

```
\b(?!(new|false|true|for|while)\b)\w+\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW1gX8/4)

`(?!new|false|true|for|while)` is negative lookahead here that asserts to fail the match if any of the given keywords are present. `\b` is used for word boundary.

Comment: the above regex does not match "newly" I believe, because it starts with the word "new". Good try tough

Comment: @YahyaUddin: Try it now. I had a typo earlier, fixed now.

Comment: yes, it ensures that those words are all stand-alone words (it is equivalent to adding something like a `\s` or `\W` token